# Why does the official Puppet style guide insist on aligned fat arrows?

Tags: puppet

From http://docs.puppetlabs.com/guides/style_guide.html:

> All of the fat comma arrows (`=>`) in a resource’s attribute/value list should be aligned. The arrows should be placed one space ahead of the longest attribute name.

This seems counterproductive. Take their "bad" example:

```
exec { 'test':
  subscribe   => File['/etc/test'],
  refreshonly => true,
}
```

If you added a attribute whose name was longer than "refreshonly", you would have to realign all those arrows, like so:

```
exec { 'test':
  subscribe       => File['/etc/test'],
  refreshonly     => true,
  somenewproperty => whatever,
}
```

Every single attribute in that resource would need to be changed, for the sake of a single line being changed. This muddies the revision history, and defeats the purpose of putting a trailing comma at the end of an attribute/value declaration (otherwise, appending a new attr/val will require a comma to be appended to the previously-last line, causing two lines to be changed instead of one).

Why does the official Puppet style guide recommend this convention?

Comment: I think I would ask the Puppet documentation maintainers.  They've a developers list as well as IRC.

Comment: Good version control can ignore whitespace-only changes, so that argument really doesn't fly.

Comment: If you don't like their style guide, don't follow their style guide.

Answer (score 3):

Most style conventions address a few points:

- Improve readability.
- Dissuade people from bad code habits.
- Urge people into long-accepted practices (no matter how bad they are).

Aligning fat arrows is readability style-point.